# Show Details in Bootstrap Modal Form, .net core

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

I am trying to edit the record which belongs to index view id
modal popup is open but id is null in controller so it is showing blank form.
I am sharing my code below

_Model.cshtml  view in shared folder

```
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="modal-create-edit-user-label" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="modal-create-edit-user" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    </div>
</div>
```

Popup is calling here in Index view to get details

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary popup" data-url="Ledger/CreateEdit" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#modal-create-edit-user" id="UserModal" data-id="@item.Id">Add New User <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
```

_LedgerPartial.cshtml - Partial view

```
@model CoreProj.Models.PaymentTbl
<!--Modal Body Start-->

@{
    Layout = "";
}

<div class="modal-content">

    <!--Modal Header Start-->
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add User</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
    </div>
    <!--Modal Header End-->


    <form asp-action="CreateEdit" asp-controller="Ledger" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group row">
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mda, new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-form-label" })
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.Mda" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FileNo, new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-form-label" })
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea asp-for="@Model.FileNo" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your address here" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsApproved, new { @class = "form-check-input" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsApproved, new { @class = "form-check-label" })
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!--Modal Footer Start-->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button data-dismiss="modal" id="cancel" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success relative" id="btnSubmit" type="submit">
                <i class="loader"></i>
                Submit
            </button>
        </div>
        <!--Modal Footer End-->
    </form>

</div>
```

Controller

```
   public IActionResult CreateEdit(int? id)
        {

                //if (id == null)
                //{
                //    return NotFound();
                //}

                var paymentTbl = _context.PaymentTbls.Find(id);
                if (paymentTbl == null)
                {
                   // return NotFound();
                }
                return PartialView("_LedgerPartial",paymentTbl);

        }
```

js code

```
(function ($) {  
    function Index() {  
        var $this = this;  
        function initialize() {  
  
            $(".popup").on('click', function (e) {  
                modelPopup(this);  
            });  
  
            function modelPopup(reff) {  
                var url = $(reff).data('url');  
  
                $.get(url).done(function (data) {  
                    debugger;  
                    $('#modal-create-edit-user').find(".modal-dialog").html(data);  
                    $('#modal-create-edit-user > .modal', data).modal("show");  
                });  
  
            }  
        }  
  
        $this.init = function () {  
            initialize();  
        };  
    }  
    $(function () {  
        var self = new Index();  
        self.init();  
    });  
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're not adding the `id` to the request in

```
$.get(url)
```

As you can see in the documentation for [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) you can pass the data in as the second parameter:

```
function modelPopup(reff) {  
    var url = $(reff).data('url');
    var id = $(reff).data('id'); // Gets data from the "data-id" attribute

    $.get(url, { id: id }).done(function (data) {  
        // ...
    });  
}
```

The controller action should now get the `id`  you put in `data-id="@item.Id"`.